# Using scala generics and manifest to cast within a class

Tags: scala, type-erasure, erasure

I have two classes, Holders (for lack of a better name at the moment) and Holder.
Holder has to be interfaced through Holders, which has an array of Holder of any type.
As such, it has to take Any type. I want to have the setValue do type checking that the Any input is indeed of type T.
I've read a bit about using manifests, but I'm getting somewhat lost. Is there any way to do what I want?

```
class Holders {
    var values = Array[Any]()
    var _holders = Array[Holder[_]]()

    def setData(index: Int, newValue: Any) {
        values(index) = newValue
        _holders(index).setValue(newValue)
    }
}

class Holder[T](someData: String, initValue: T) {
    private var value : T = initValue
    def getValue : T = value
    def setValue(newValue: Any)(implicit m: Manifest[T]) = {
      if (newValue.isInstanceOf[T])
        value = newValue.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.

*note: `Manifest` is deprecated and replaced with `TypeTag` and `ClassTag`, but that doesn't affect the remainder of this answer*

Often when wanting Manifests/TypeTags you know exactly what's happening at compile time but want that information preserved through to runtime as well.  In this case you also have to deal with the fact that, even at compile time, `_holders(index)` can't tell you what kind of `Holder` it's returning.

Depending on how `_holders` will be built, it may be possible to replace it with an [Heterogeneous Map](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview%3a-shapeless-2.0.0#heterogenous-maps) from the shapeless library, that would do exactly what you need out-of-the-box.

Otherwise, you have the right idea, testing the type at runtime.  The trick is using `TypeTag` to capture both the underlying type of the holder *and* the type of the new value.

Note that the `TypeTag` context bound has to be specified on all the nested methods so it can be passed down the call stack in implicit scope.  Presence of the `TypeTag` is what allows `typeOf` to then work.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._ //for TypeTag

class Holders {
  var values = Array[Any]()
  var _holders = Array[Holder[_]]()

  def setData[V: TypeTag](index: Int, newValue: V): Unit = {
    values(index) = newValue
    _holders(index).setValue(newValue)
  }
}

class Holder[T: TypeTag](someData: String, initValue: T) {
  private var value: T = initValue
  def getValue: T = value

  def setValue[V: TypeTag](newValue: V): Unit =
    if(typeOf[V] <:< typeOf[T]) {
      value = newValue.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Or using `Manifest`

```
class Holder[T: Manifest](someData: String, initValue: T) {
  private var value: T = initValue
  def getValue: T = value

  def setValue[V: Manifest](newValue: V): Unit =
    if(manifest[V] <:< manifest[T]) {
      value = newValue.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

I'd strongly urge you to favour `TypeTag` though!

Comment: in your example, isn't testing T in setValue not doing anything because of type erasure? I get a warning when I try what you have

Comment: This will not work due to erasure, as `case nv: T` is true for any possible `nv`.

Comment: so is there any way for me to check if my Any is of type T?

Comment: why doesn't manifest support =:= :(
is comparing manifest[T].runtimeClass == manifest[V].runtimeClass equivalent?

Comment: You don't want `=:=` here. I'm assuming that you want to be able to put a `FordFiesta` in a `Holder[Car]`

Answer (score 2):

Type erasure makes this kind of thing... hard. In a nutshell once your code is compiled, all type parameters are replaced with `Any`. To understand the implications, consider the following example:

```
trait Foo[T] { def isT(a: Any): Boolean = a.isInstanceOf[T] }

object Bar extends Foo[String]

Bar.isT("foo") // true
Bar.isT(42)    // also true, as Int <: Any
```

This will produce a warning when compiled with the appropriate options.

In this scenario you have two options; you can compare `TypeTag`s, in which case you hope that the provided type parameters are sufficiently accurate (consider the provided type parameter could be any superclass of `value`), or you compare the runtime classes of your values (in which case you are out of luck when dealing with generic types). A `TypeTag`-based solution might look something like this:

```
class Holder[T : TypeTag](someData: String, initValue: T) {
  private var value = initValue
  def setValue[V : TypeTag](v: V): Unit = {
    // Works because there are TypeTags for T and V in implicit scope
    if(typeOf[V] <:< typeOf[T])
      value = v.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

Now you are looking at this and saying "well doesn't that mean that the assignment is actually `value = v.asInstanceOf[Any]`?" and the answer is yes - `value` is also erased to `Any`.  Casting does **nothing**, in the sense that `v.asInstanceOf[T]` does not mean "convert `v` to a `T`". Instead what you are doing is saying "oh yeah, `v` is totally a `T` - honest!", and because the compiler is naive, it believes you.

Comment: would using =:= fix my super class issues?

Comment: Is there any way to do the exact same thing using manifest? Ideally I would stick with scala2.8

Comment: I believe you should be able to accomplish the same thing using manifests in place of tags, as `TypeTag` is the evolution of manifests integrated with a reflection API - see the API documentation: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest

Comment: The 'supertype problem' derives from the fact that the caller can 'lie' by 'under-reporting' the type of the argument, e.g. `setValue[Any]("foo")`. It is also worth noting that what you are getting is the *declared* type, when often what you really want is the *runtime* type.

Comment: Under what circumstances is sticking with 2.8 "ideal"?